# Does scrapy view uses active project settings?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-shell

Does `scrapy view` use active project settings(especially middleware)? I want to use Scrapy Fake User Agent and Scrapy Crawlera on `scrapy view`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy commands should use your project settings if executed at the root of a project, including `scrapy view`.

Alternatively, you can [use `-s`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#command-line-options) to set settings in the command line.